# FPS Mouse movement in OpenGL (even outside window)

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm creating a simple FPS game where the camera movement is controlled with the mouse. It's fairly simple to move the camera with the mouse when it's inside the window. But how can I make this work even when I'm OUT of the window?

I've heard some thing about fixing the mouse in the center of the screen, but I'm not sure how to get this to work.

I currently have the following:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
    x = X;
    y = Y;
    X = event.getX();
    Y = event.getY();
}

public void update() {
    dX = X - x;
    dY = Y - y;
    x = X;
    y = Y;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've heard some thing about fixing the mouse in the center of the screen, but I'm not sure how to get this to work.

That is a very common way to do it. After you have checked how much your mouse has moved and used that information for camera movement, just move the cursor back to screen center.

Consider something like this:

```
Vec2 mouseDelta = getMousePosition();
camera.CalculateMovement(mouseDelta);
setMousePosition(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "capture" the mouse in your window, typically on the mouse down ( don't forget to release it ).

```
onMouseDown()
{
    BeginCapture();
}

... 


ReleaseCapture();
```